# how can set todays time in my Reminder app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i am working on a Reminder app in windows phone my problem is if i want to set the reminder today for  one hour ahead what i am seeing is my reminder is set but time it is showing is negative value .

The coding i have done is for future date then the time is ok .My code is

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titlebox.Text))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(descriptionbox.Text))
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)beginDatePicker.Value;
        DateTime time = (DateTime)beginTimePicker.Value;
        DateTime beginTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;
        if (beginTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Date must be in the future.");
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = false;
            result = this.personalViewModel.ReminderSaveDetail(this.personalViewModel.PersonalModel);
            if (result)
            {
                //NavigationService.GoBack();
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PersonalReminder.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Description");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Title");
}
```

Comment: How would you expect `if (beginTime < DateTime.Now && beginTime == DateTime.Now)` to execute? How can it be before now *and equal to now* at the same time?

Comment: This code has other problems anyway I.E. DateTime setTime = time.TimeOfDay + MessageBox.Show("The Date must be in the future."); Not sure how you can add a time of day plus a messagebox and get anything meaningful...